# Volley gson request on a ExpandableListView causes java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley, expandablelistview

I have list of orders, in recyclerview, when I click on one of the orders, a new activity shows that displays an expandable list of the sub-orders of that main order, now at the header of each sub-order I must show the name of the vendor and the sub-order total price..!

I used [this](https://github.com/SilenceDut/ExpandableLayout) library for the ExpandableListView it's great, it worked for me normally when I used static data, now when I tried to populated with json data from server, it keeps giving me the error mentioned below, I json pretty complex but I've tried for days and no luck, the model data are generated by Pojo.!

> the json link below is a simplified replica of the actual link I'm
>   using since the one I'm using is filled with data (you need a minutes
>   of scrolling to see the last of it) but the one below has the exact
>   same structure..!

[JSON URL Link](http://www.mocky.io/v2/58ee239e0f00009317787ee4)

**The Error**

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
                                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                                       at com.alaasamizarifa.driver_aghrady.FrontEnd.Adapters.ExpandAdapter$ReyclerViewHolder.SetHeaderData(ExpandAdapter.java:90)
                                                                                       at com.alaasamizarifa.driver_aghrady.FrontEnd.Adapters.ExpandAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ExpandAdapter.java:57)
                                                                                       at com.alaasamizarifa.driver_aghrady.FrontEnd.Adapters.ExpandAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ExpandAdapter.java:23)
                                                                                       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6356)
```

**The request inside the repository**

```
 final JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getOrdersURL(FETCH_ORDERS_URI, userID), null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<OrderPresenter>>() {
                     }.getType();
                    try {

                       List<OrderPresenter> TheOrders;
                        TheOrders = gson.fromJson(response.getJSONArray("orders").toString(), listType);
                        ArrayList<OrderPresenter> result = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (OrderPresenter sub : TheOrders) {
                            sub.getSubOrders().toString();
                            result.addAll(TheOrders);
                        }
                        refreshUi.onSuccess(result);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                     refreshUi.onFail(e);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "catched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                   refreshUi.onFail(error);
                }
            });
```

**The Adapter**

```
   public class ExpandAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExpandAdapter.ReyclerViewHolder> {
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private HashSet<Integer> expandedPositionSet = new HashSet<>();
ArrayList<OrderPresenter> theSubOrders;
private Context context;

public ExpandAdapter(ArrayList<OrderPresenter> theSubOrders, Context context) {
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.theSubOrders = theSubOrders;

}

@Override
public ReyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View item = layoutInflater.inflate(viewType == 0 ? R.layout.cart_item : R.layout.cart_item, parent, false);


    return new ReyclerViewHolder(item);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ReyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

   /* this for showing the icon indicator when expanded or not */
    holder.updateItem(position);

   /* what causes the crash */
    holder.SetHeaderData(theSubOrders.get(position), position);
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return theSubOrders.size();
}

class ReyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView subOrderVendorName;
    private TextView subOrderTotalPrice;

    private ExpandableLayout expandableLayout;
    private ImageView showInfo;


    private ReyclerViewHolder(final View view) {
        super(view);

        subOrderVendorName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sub_order_vendor_name);
        subOrderTotalPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sub_order_total_price);
        expandableLayout = (ExpandableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_layout);
        showInfo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.showChild);
    }

    public void SetHeaderData(final OrderPresenter data, final int position) {

 subOrderVendorName.setText(data.getSubOrders().get(position).getLineItems().get(position).getProductObject().getVendorName());

        subOrderTotalPrice.setText(data.getSubOrders().get(position).getTotal());   

    }

    private void updateItem(final int position) {
        expandableLayout.setOnExpandListener(new ExpandableLayout.OnExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public void onExpand(boolean expanded) {
                registerExpand(position, showInfo);

            }
        });
        expandableLayout.setExpand(expandedPositionSet.contains(position));

    }
}

private void registerExpand(int position, ImageView plus) {
    if (expandedPositionSet.contains(position)) {
        removeExpand(position);
        plus.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_circle);
    } else {
        addExpand(position);
        plus.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_remove_circle);
    }
}

private void removeExpand(int position) {
    expandedPositionSet.remove(position);
}

private void addExpand(int position) {
    expandedPositionSet.add(position);
}
}
```

**The activity that shows the data**

```
public class OrderDetails extends BaseActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
ExpandAdapter expandAdapter;
ArrayList<OrderPresenter> OrderDetailsList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_details);
    this.title = getString(R.string.OrderDetails);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);

    OrderDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    expandAdapter = new ExpandAdapter(OrderDetailsList, this);
    expandAdapter.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(expandAdapter);

    OrderRepository.SubOrdersRequest(this, OrderDetailsList, new RefreshUi() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object o) {

            OrderDetailsList.addAll((Collection<? extends OrderPresenter>) o);
            Toast.makeText(OrderDetails.this, "" + OrderDetailsList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            expandAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFail(Object o) {

        }
    });


}
}
```

**Update**

---

The models classes

[OrderPresenter Class](https://gist.github.com/AlaaZarifa/6632072c6ea05a6e52eaefddebc4c09c)

[Order Class](https://gist.github.com/AlaaZarifa/d520080a364282865e3522e56e5b1344)

[Sub_Orders Class](https://gist.github.com/AlaaZarifa/5629febfa2a9679e38381a9dcaafd5c9)

Answer (score 1):

Problem inside `onBindViewHolder` method of your adapter. First call `theSubOrders.get(position)` shouldn't make any problems, but result of it sends to `holder.SetHeaderData` method, where again getting sub elements `data.getSubOrders().get(position).getTotal()` with same `position` value. May be you mean to use `data.getTotal()` instead?

**Lets see closer.**

```
public void SetHeaderData(final OrderPresenter data, final int position) {
    subOrderVendorName.setText(
        data.getSubOrders().get(position) //first
         .getLineItems().get(position) //second
         .getProductObject().getVendorName());
    subOrderTotalPrice.setText(data.getSubOrders().get(position).getTotal()); //third
}
```

You are using `position` variable 3 times in your method. And it is ubnormal, because it is position of your `data` variable in `theSubOrders` list. So you need to change this method totally.

Best way to remove second parameter of method to make it like `public void SetHeaderData(final OrderPresenter data)`. But I don't know your algorithm of adapter work, so I can't get advice of replacing code. Another way - before **every** `get(position)` call place check of list size. But for me it seems wrong.

```
if(data.getSubOrders().size() > position) {
    ... subList = data.getSubOrders().get(position);
    if(subList.size() > position) {
        ... //etc
    }
}
```

Comment: let's you want get the vendor_name and total from json url I added and show them in the textviews mentioned in the viewholder,, ..! how's your volley request will be and how the setData method will be like,..!? please man I'm drawing for days over this.!!

Comment: @SamZar I don't know what `OrderPresenter` class contains. Can you post its code?